# Airplay support iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, airplay

I'am trying to add airplay for my audio app. Here is my code

```
let buttonView  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
let routerPickerView =  AVRoutePickerView(frame: buttonView.bounds)
routerPickerView.tintColor = UIColor.white
routerPickerView.activeTintColor = UIColor.white
buttonView.addSubview(routerPickerView)
self.btnsStack.addArrangedSubview(buttonView)
```

This works well with my Mac, but when I try to play it with my Samsung Smart TV,  there is a loader keeps on spinning. I tried connecting my TV with other apps like Spotify and it works.

Comment: Does your smartTV is compatible with AirPlay ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Found my solution, so for casting airplay with smart tv one line of code is must

```
    player?.allowsExternalPlayback = false
```

player is your AVPlayer.